# Algorithm for creating unique bingo faces

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can generate unique bingo card faces? I'm looking to implement this algorithm in C#.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20090100118 It's probably patented though.

Comment: @dtb: I give you the award for understatement of the year: you link to a patent on a patents site and then warn that the idea is "probably patented." hehe

Comment: Note that there are 111,007,923,832,370,565 possible different bingo cards, assuming US cards (3003 permutations per column, 1365 for the middle one). The chance of getting duplicates is incredibly small.

Comment: And here I thought that algorithms couldn't be patented.

Comment: Addon comment: The number of possible bingo cards I provided only applies if you define "unique" as containing different numbers, ignoring ordering within the columns. If you consider two cards different even if only the in-column ordering is different (meaning "1 2 3 4 5" is different from "5 4 3 2 1"), the number of possible cards goes to a whopping 552,446,474,061,128,648,601,600,000. That's **552 septillion, or a little over half an octillion.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get 5 sets containing 15 numbers each (1-15 for set 1, 16-30 for set 2...)
select 5 different numbers in sets 1,2,4,5
select 4 different numbers in set 3

To check if that card already exists
Check each existing card for top left correspondance with new card
if both numbers are equal, then move to the second number
if you get 24 times the same number at the same place then both cards are equal and new card must be rejected

Comment: Maybe you could come up with a function that hashes the bingo card uniquely instead of having to compare every value?

Comment: ended up doing something slightly different but along similar lines as to what you suggested above and used a dictionary to hash the patterns of the 5 columns (reducing each column into a permutation of 5 numbers out of 15) and it seems to work quite well both in performance and memory usage

Comment: I'm not sure it is more efficient since you always have to hash 24 numbers while the in if solution, you have 1 comparison in the best case scenario. It would be correct to do a little distribution probability and unless you generate a huge amount of cards, I doubt you will have that many collisions

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, but as Michael Madsen reported, given the number of possibilities, you would probably be better generate them randomly and **after**, check if you have duplicates. (Unless you want to generate all 111 quadrillion possibilities, which I hope you have data storage space for!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for generating a random subset of integers from a given range which you might find useful:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> RandomSubsetOfRange(int min, int max, int count)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    int size = max - min + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i += 1)
    {
        if (random.NextDouble() <= ((float)count / (float)(size - i + 1)))
        {
            yield return min + i;
            count -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```