A Laravel PHP function to generate 90 unique value for 90 fields
I want to generate set of tickets. In one set it has 6 tickets. In one ticket it has 27 fields from b_1 to b_27. That is shown in three rows where every row has 9 fields & 5 values.
In first row it has from b_1 to b_9, In 2nd row it has from b_10 to b_18 & in third row it has b_19 to b_27.
For all the tickets this is the format in the data is showing. So, in the image you can see we have total 6*3 = 18 rows, every rows with 9 columns.
We have total 90 values in these fields from 1 to 90 & every value is unique. Any value is not coming twice.
In the every column we have 18 fields & for 1 tickets we have 3 fields.
In 1st column the value comes between 1 to 9 - 9 value
In 2st column the value comes between 10 to 19 - 10 value
In 3st column the value comes between 20 to 29 - 10 value
In 4st column the value comes between 30 to 39 - 10 value
In 5st column the value comes between 40 to 49 - 10 value
In 6st column the value comes between 50 to 59 - 10 value
In 7st column the value comes between 60 to 69 - 10 value
In 8st column the value comes between 70 to 79 - 10 value
In 9st column the value comes between 80 to 90 - 11 value
enter image description here
<?php

function findValueIndex($value)
{
    $col = array(
        array(1, 10, 19),
        array(2, 11, 20),
        array(3, 12, 21),
        array(4, 13, 22),
        array(5, 14, 23),
        array(6, 15, 24),
        array(7, 16, 25),
        array(8, 17, 26),
        array(9, 18, 27)
    );
    // Search for the row (index) that contains the value
    $rowIndex = array_search(true, array_map(function ($row) use ($value) {
        return in_array($value, $row);
    }, $col));

    return $rowIndex;
}


function createGameTokens($initialSetNumber, $noOfSets)
{
    $tokens = [];

    for ($setNumber = $initialSetNumber; $setNumber <= $noOfSets; $setNumber++) {
        // Insert Sets
        $colPool_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // Initialize pool  1–9
        $colPool_2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]; // Initialize pool 10–19
        $colPool_3 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]; // Initialize pool 20–29
        $colPool_4 = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]; // Initialize pool 30–39
        $colPool_5 = [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]; // Initialize pool 40–49
        $colPool_6 = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]; // Initialize pool 50–59
        $colPool_7 = [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]; // Initialize pool 60–69
        $colPool_8 = [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]; // Initialize pool 70–79
        $colPool_9 = [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]; // Initialize 80–90
        // Initialize column pools
        $colPools = [
            $colPool_1,
            $colPool_2,
            $colPool_3,
            $colPool_4,
            $colPool_5,
            $colPool_6,
            $colPool_7,
            $colPool_8,
            $colPool_9
        ];

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) { //For one set 6 tickets
            // // Prepare ticket data
            $ticketData = [];
            for ($row = 1; $row <= 3; $row++) {
                $fieldsData = [];
                $fields = range((($row - 1) * 9) + 1, $row * 9); // Row-wise fields

                while (count($fieldsData) < 5) {
                    // Filter valid fields (fields with non-empty pools)
                    $validFields = array_filter($fields, function ($field) use ($colPools) {
                        $colIndex = findValueIndex($field);
                        return !empty($colPools[$colIndex]);
                    });

                    if (empty($validFields)) {
                        break; // Exit if no valid fields are left
                    }

                    // Pick a random valid field
                    $selectedField = $validFields[array_rand($validFields)];
                    $selectedFieldCol = findValueIndex($selectedField);
                    shuffle($colPools[$selectedFieldCol]); 
                    // Pick a random number from the corresponding column pool
                    $selectedNumber = array_shift($colPools[$selectedFieldCol]);

                    if ($selectedNumber !== null) {
                        // Assign the field and value
                        $fieldsData['b_' . $selectedField] = $selectedNumber;
                        $fields = array_diff($fields, [$selectedField]); // Remove field
                    }
                }

                // If the row is incomplete due to field exhaustion, log an error
                if (count($fieldsData) < 5) {
                    // echo "Error";
                    // print_r([
                    //     'row' => $row,
                    //     'fieldsData' => $fieldsData,
                    //     'remainingPools' => $colPools,
                    // ]);
                }

                $ticketData = array_merge($ticketData, $fieldsData);
            }
            // print_r($ticketData);
            echo "<table style='margin-top: 10px;'>";
            for($row = 1; $row <= 3; $row++) {
                echo "<tr >";
                for($col = 1; $col <= 9; $col++) {
                    $number = ($row - 1) * 9 + $col;
                    if(isset($ticketData['b_'.$number])) {
                        echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>".$ticketData['b_'.$number]."</td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
                    }
                    
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                // echo "<br>";
            }
            
            echo "</table>";
        }
        echo "Remaining data";
        // Insert tickets in batches
        print_r($colPools);
    }
}
createGameTokens(1, 1);

Output


<table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>18</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>21</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>44</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>58</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>77</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>4</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>26</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>36</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>56</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>83</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>24</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>52</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>66</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>71</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>82</td></tr></table><table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>11</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>51</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>69</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>70</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>85</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>3</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>10</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>33</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>41</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>88</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>6</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>28</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>35</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>47</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>67</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>8</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>25</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>37</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>68</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>86</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>7</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>16</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>22</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>59</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>84</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>14</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>27</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>38</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>40</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>81</td></tr></table><table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>5</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>17</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>43</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>57</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>74</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>12</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>34</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>50</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>64</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>90</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>1</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>19</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>39</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>48</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>89</td></tr></table><table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>2</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>15</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>46</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>75</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>80</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>9</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>13</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>45</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>53</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>65</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>20</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>31</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>63</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>72</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>87</td></tr></table><table style='margin-top: 10px;'><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>23</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>32</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>49</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>55</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>73</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>29</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>42</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>54</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>60</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>78</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr ><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>30</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>61</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:#dbd816; padding: 5px;'>79</td><td style='border: 1px solid #000;background:green; padding: 5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table>



Desired result
The last table has only 13 values but it should be 15 exactly. The same is showing in the output.
This function is able to generate value for the first 5 tickets. I mean for the first 5 tickets it generating 15 numbers correctly. But for the last row its not able to generate 15 numbers.
I have attached the working link of the above code to test & verify.
https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/0kNQhgBkKAo6R

"Stuck" how exactly? That's not a meaningful description. Is there an error? Do you get unexpected results? What debugging have you done, to try and narrow down the problem? Please be clearer and more specific, so that we can help you more easily. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your question.  Thanks

@ADyson
I have updated the code with minimum running example with output & also attached the working code link. Thanks

since you are trying to generate bingo cards, does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113718/algorithm-for-creating-unique-bingo-faces
